# async issue with slice function using javascript

Tags: javascript

i have the following code but the slice function is not working as expected

```
  for (const id of input.campaignIds) {
    exsitingAffiliates = context.metadataService
      .getAffiliates("'" + id + "'", ChimdsdseraCollection.Campaigns)
      .catch(() => null)
    exsitingAffiliates.then(result => {
      for (const affiliate of apiInput) {
        const affiliatesDB = result.map(a => a.a_list_fk_i_id_tbl_affiliates)
        const mode = result.map(campaign => campaign.e_list_affiliate_mode)
        let DbAffiliates = JSON.parse(affiliatesDB[0].replace(/\'/gi, ''))
        let found = DbAffiliates.includes(affiliate)
        if (found) {
          if (mode == 'WHITE') {
            console.log(affiliate)
            console.log('DbAffiliates'+DbAffiliates)
            finalArray1 = DbAffiliates.slice(affiliate)
            console.log('FINAL array' + finalArray1)
```

this returns

```
2
DbAffiliates1,5,2,3
FINAL array2,3
1
DbAffiliates1,5,2,3
FINAL array5,2,3
```

when it should return

```
2
DbAffiliates1,5,2,3
FINAL array1,5,3
1
DbAffiliates1,5,2,3
FINAL array 5,3
```

i tried everything but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: `slice` argument is the **index** that points to the start of extraction. What you seem to expect it removes the element from the array. This however requires [different approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/48vnpjrs/

Comment: this seems to work and thats slice so what is it?

Comment: It doesn't work. Change `array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]` to `array1= [5,4,3,2,1]`. You still seem to missunderstand how slice works.

Comment: you are right. so how this can be solved?

Comment: Look again into my first comment, you have the solution under the link.

Comment: i used it but i still have issue: finalArray---[5,3,1] and then
finalArray---[5,2,3]